# Centering a Text on a DIV is not working

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS3 div style definition

```
.title {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    letter-spacing: 2.1em;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
```

I use that div and I see this:

[image]

The title is not centered inside the DIV box. I have tried to change a lot of things.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are missing **dot** in selector in your code. Class selector should be ".title" not "title" if it is <div class="title">...

Comment: if its an id then #title..

Comment: sorry about that it was a copy/paste problem when I copied the code to here. The original code has the dot and it is still out of center

Comment: can you add the html for us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
title {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    letter-spacing: 2.1em;
    text-indent: 2.1em;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
```

Comment: YESSSSSSS, you are right. The problem here is not the centering. The problem here is the `letter-spacing` and how stupid is the CSS implementation of it. `letter-spacing`, like the name say, should be space between letters but the geniuses behind the CSS implementation created that in a way that a 2.1em space is added after the last letter, what is wrong because there is no letter after the last one. That last space makes the word be out of center. On your answer you added an indent of 2.1, compensating for the problem. YOU ARE A GENIUS. I don't understand why people down voted you. THANKS!!!!

Comment: np I'm glad I helped :D

Answer (score 0):

```
title {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    letter-spacing: 2.1em;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
transform:translateX:(-50%);
    }
```

and in obove div

```
divclassname {
position: relative;
}
```